# Does it matter whether you first write down the primary key or foreign key, when you use join?

Tags: sql

When I use join, by the ON part I write down the connection, foreign key = primary key.

But when I reverse the fk and pk I still get the same result, does this mean that it doesn't matter which one goes first?

Example:

```
select
  movie.title,
  director.firstname,
  director.lastname
from movie
join director on movie.director = director.directorcode
```

(This is the one with the right order FK=PK)

```
select
  movie.title,
  director.firstname,
  director.lastname
from movie
join director on director.directorcode = movie.director
```

Comment: equals is commutative operation, it does not matter whether a==b or b==a

Comment: how about `where 1 = 1` and `where 1 = 1` - did you notice I a swapped the 1s over? you are talking about either side of an equivalence... they are either equivalent or they are not!

Comment: Technically it doesn't matter. Semantically, it might be beneficial to use the "correct" direction in the query (in your case `movie.director = director.directorcode`). I personally start with the field in the table that is being joined (in your case `director.directorcode = movie.director`). Also note that, technically, you even don't need to have foreign key to be able to join tables in a query. Your query will work even if your `movie` table doesn't have a foreign key to the `director` table. (Which doesn't imply that foreign keys are unnecessary!)

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. SQL is a declarative language. The engine will rephrase the query behind the scenes anyway, so whichever form you choose the actual executed query will be normalized internally, before being executed.

Comment: As has already been said: The order doesn't matter. Why should it? It would be strange if it did. It is personal preference which order to use. We join the directors on their code so that it matches the movie code, so my preference is to write it in the same order as I word it: `join director on director.directorcode = movie.director`. Decide for one way and stick to it. Be consistent when writing SQL, so as to have your queries readable. The same goes for names, by the way. If I call that column `directorcode`, then I don't call it `director` only in another table.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in both cases the FK and PK columns refer to the same values.

In a SQL join operation, the result of the join will be the same regardless of the order of the FK and PK in the join condition, as long as the FK and PK columns refer to the same values.

The purpose of the join condition is to match up rows from the two tables based on the values in the FK and PK columns.

Answer (score -1):

It does not matters what you write first in equals operation.